# jQuery, javascript: several forms same submit button text - how to determine value of closest hidden value box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have several forms in HTML, each with a submit button and a hidden field.  The same javascript function is called when any of the submit buttons are pushed.  I want to know which submit button has been pushed.  I think I can do this by finding out what the hidden field value is of the corresponding form - but I'm having difficulty with this.  My HTML is:

```
<div id="existingPhotosList">
<table><tbody><tr><td>
    <img src="./userPictures/IMG0001.jpg">
</td>
<td>
    <form class="deleteFiles">
        <input type="hidden" name="picture" value="IMG0001.jpg">
        <input type="submit" name="deleteFile" value="Delete File">
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <img src="./userPictures/IMG0002.jpg">
</td>
<td>
    <form class="deleteFiles">
        <input type="hidden" name="picture" value="IMG0002.jpg">
        <input type="submit" name="deleteFile" value="Delete File">
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

There may be more or less table rows with images and forms on them - depending on how many images are found on the server.

The javascript I have right now is:

```
$('.deleteFiles').submit(deleteFile);

function deleteFile()  {

    var myValue = $(this).parent().closest(".picture").val();
    alert(myValue);

    return false;

}
```

I'm currently getting undefined as the result of the alert.

Comment: Can't you set a ID for each button one?

Comment: I hadn't thought of adding an ID for each button.  But I think it would be the same amount of work doing it that way.  I want the name of the file in the deleteFile() function so I can then send an AJAX query to the server and delete this image there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know which submit button has been pushed.

As each of your forms only has one submit, you don't have to change your code much.

`this` in your `submit` handler will refer to the `form`, and the element is *within* the form, so:

```
var myValue = $(this).find("input[name=picture]").val();
```

No need to go up to the parent, and `closest` goes up the ancestry (through ancestors), not down. `find` goes down (descendants).

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  It works.  It's also probably the simplest way that isn't delicate on how the HTML is ordered.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way I think will be:

```
var myValue = $('input[name=picture]', this).val();
```

Comment: That's *really* delicate. Just a tiny change to the HTML blows it up (like moving the submit prior to the hidden field). Also, FWIW, `$(selector, context)` is just converted to `$(context).find(selector)` within jQuery.

Comment: agree... added selector by name [name=picture]

Comment: Thanks!  It works.  I agree - it's probably the simplest way.  Oh - didn't realize it was so delicate.  Will use solution by T.J. Crowder below.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
var myValue = $(this).closest(".deleteFiles").find("input[type=hidden]").val();
```

Comment: Why would you need `.closest(".deleteFiles")` when `this` is *already* the `form.deleteFiles` element? It's harmless, but pointless.

Comment: becaused i skimmed through the code, it works doesnt it?

Comment: This works.  I agree with T.J. Crowder, however, that I was making my code unnecessarily complex by adding the .closest in there.  The method provided by T.J. Crowder below is probably the best.

Answer (score -1):

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/symonsarwar/963aV/

```
$('.deleteFiles').click(deleteFile);
function deleteFile()  {
var me=$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val();
    alert(me)
}
```